react native app crashes wen using react native gesture handler
I'm trying to build a task page with the ability to long press and drag each task around. Did some digging around and found the react native gesture handler. I got it working at one stage but I left the app for a while and tried implementing it again but the app keeps crashing whenever i try long press and drag the task around with no errors frustratingly. Below is the screen in question, idk if its logic problem or something else. If anyone has any experience with react native gesture handler, or suggestions to be resolve this or know any other library I could use that would work would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.
        import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
        import {
          Text,
          View,
          Alert,
          SafeAreaView,
          ScrollView,
          RefreshControl,
          StyleSheet,
          Animated,
        } from "react-native";
        import { FirebaseAuth, firestoredb } from "../../firebaseConfig";
        import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
        import {
          GestureHandlerRootView,
          GestureDetector,
          Gesture,
        } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

        export const AppScreen = () => {
          const auth = FirebaseAuth;
          const user = auth.currentUser;
          const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
          const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

          const panRefs = useRef(
            tasks.map(() => ({
              x: new Animated.Value(0),
              y: new Animated.Value(0),
            }))
          ).current;
          console.log(panRefs);

          const generateGesturePanHandlers = useCallback(() => {
            return tasks.map((_, index) => {
              const panGesture = Gesture.Pan()
                .onTouchesUp(() => {
                  console.log("touched");
                })
                .activateAfterLongPress(500)
                .onBegin(() => {
                  console.log("long pressed");
                })
                .onUpdate((event) => {
                  panRefs[index].x.setValue(event.translationX);
                  panRefs[index].y.setValue(event.translationY);
                })
                .onEnd(() => {
                  console.log("ended");
                  panRefs[index].x.setValue(0);
                  panRefs[index].y.setValue(0);
                });

              return panGesture;
            });
          }, [tasks, panRefs]);

          const gestureHandlers = generateGesturePanHandlers();

          const onRefresh = () => {
            setRefreshing(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              setRefreshing(false);
            }, 1000);
          };

          const getDataFromDatabase = async () => {
            try {
              const q = query(
                collection(firestoredb, "tasks"),
                where("taskType", "==", "todo")
              );
              const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
              const dataList = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
              setTasks(dataList);
            } catch (error) {
              Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to get data from database");
            }
          };

          useEffect(() => {
            getDataFromDatabase();
          }, [refreshing]);

          useEffect(() => {
            panRefs.map(() => ({
              x: new Animated.Value(0),
              y: new Animated.Value(0),
            }));
          }, [tasks]);

          return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
              <ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollView}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={refreshing}
                    onRefresh={onRefresh}
                    tintColor="#C79471"
                  />
                }
              >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                  {tasks.map((item, index) => (
                    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container} key={index}>
                      <GestureDetector gesture={gestureHandlers[index]}>
                        <View style={styles.taskContainer}>
                          <Animated.View
                            style={[
                              {
                                transform: [
                                  { translateX: panRefs[index].x },
                                  { translateY: panRefs[index].y },
                                ],
                              },
                            ]}
                            key={index}
                          >
                            <Text key={index} style={styles.taskText}>
                              {item.title}: {item.description} - {item.status}
                            </Text>
                          </Animated.View>
                        </View>
                      </GestureDetector>
                    </GestureHandlerRootView>
                  ))}
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
          );
        };

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          safeArea: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "#1E1E1E",
          },
          scrollView: {
            flex: 1,
            maxHeight: "100%",
            paddingTop: 0,
          },
          taskContainer: {
            backgroundColor: "#2E2E2E",
            padding: 20,
            borderRadius: 10,
          },
          container: {
            paddingHorizontal: 8,
            gap: 20,
          },
          taskText: {
            color: "white",
          },
        });


tried using useEffect and defining the panRefs outside of the component and a dozen other approaches... but to no avail.
